# Unable to import the libraries correctly

Tags: arduino-ide, stm32

I am trying to use the Arduino IDE 1.8.15 to program my Arduino. When I download the following code along with the libraries from the same link: https://github.com/SolidGeek/VescUart and using the example: https://github.com/SolidGeek/VescUart/tree/master/examples/getVescValuescompile it, it seems to giving me an error that the VescUart file seems to be missing. I did ctrl+shift+N and also tried adding the library files and these library files are in the same folder as the .ino code. but still it keeps giving me that the header file is missing. Can someone help me with this please?

Error message below:

```
Arduino: 1.8.15 (Windows Store 1.8.49.0) (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino MKR NB 1500"

getVescValues:9:10: fatal error: VescUart.h: No such file or directory

 #include <VescUart.h>

          ^~~~~~~~~~~~

compilation terminated.

exit status 1

VescUart.h: No such file or directory



This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

Also attached is the image for reference
[image]

Comment: Please put the library in your library folder

Comment: Thanks! that worked

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I have downloaded the library but not sure what went wrong](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/53461/i-have-downloaded-the-library-but-not-sure-what-went-wrong)